# React-table custom page size

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v6

I found this link [react-table custompagination](https://codesandbox.io/s/012ywx6mp0?file=/src/Pagination.js).  Its working perfectly. But i am not able to decide the page size, means how any item i want to show. I tried that also by editing on the existing code. follow the path link in the file new [Pagination](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-custom-pagination-5hfq4?file=/Pagination.js) where i added the size selection.
please help me out. I want the size change to reflect on the page data

Answer (score 0):

You can use Material UI Pagination.
https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/